# Load Data into JSP Page from MySQL without Form

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp

I am trying to load data into JSP page from MySQL database using Eclipse and Tomcat 8 server. My .jsp file looks as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:forward page="/ProductDisplay" />
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Phone Number</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="patients" items="${patients}">
            <tr>
                <td>${patients.getPatientId()}</td>
                <td>${patients.getPatientfName()}</td>
                <td>${patients.getPatientlName()}</td>
                <td>${patients.getPatientEmail()}</td>
                <td>${patients.getPatientPhone()}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The .java servlet file:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
* Servlet implementation class ProductDisplay
*/
@WebServlet("/ProductDisplay")
public class ProductDisplay extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
    */
    public ProductDisplay() {
        super();
    }

    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
     ServletException, IOException {
        PatientsDao p = new PatientsDao();
        ArrayList<Patient> patients = p.getPatients();
        request.setAttribute("patients", patients);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Patient.jsp").forward(request,  response);
    }
}
```

And the database connector class looks as follows:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PatientsDao {
    DBConnection mt = new DBConnection();
    Connection myConn = mt.myConn;

    private class DBConnection {
        public Connection myConn;

        public DBConnection() {

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
                myConn = 
          DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PatientsDB", "root", "");
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Patient> getPatients() {
        ArrayList<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>();
         try {
               PreparedStatement pst = 
                       myConn.prepareStatement("select * from Patients");
               ResultSet r = pst.executeQuery();
               while(r.next()) {
                   Patient p = new Patient();
                   p.setId(r.getInt("id"));
                   p.setfName(r.getString("fName"));
                   p.setlName(r.getString("lName"));
                   p.setEmail(r.getString("Email"));
                   p.setPhone(r.getString("Phone"));
                   patients.add(p);
                }
              }
               catch (SQLException exc) {
                    System.out.println("An error occured. Error: " + exc.getMessage());
           }
         return patients;
    }
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe that upon running the Tomcat server the .java servlet class is invoked and information from the database is loaded into JSP page without any action needed. However, this does not happen in my case. Once I start Tomcat server and navigate to the Patient.jsp page the only thing that is displayed is the table header (which does not come from database). No data from MySQL database is displayed.

I know that this is not a MySQL problem as I can load all the data successfully if I add a form and use a button. Once the button is clicked and doGet method is invoked everything is loaded successfully.

My question is, how would I load the data automatically, without clicking a button or a link? I was doing research and apparently all info is supposed to load automatically. This, however, does not happen in my case. Am I missing something? Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, neither your Servlet nor your JSP will be executed until an incoming request matches one of their URI patterns. Set breakpoints in all 3 file, launch the application in the Debugger, and you'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you mistake.

Servlet load first time when you call it(for examle go to *Patient.jsp*).

But when you go to *Patient.jsp* work only servlet *Patient.jsp*(jsp page convert to servlet class automatically), and you servlet */ProductDisplay* dont work at all.

Your request attribute is empty when you call Patient.jsp beacause ProductDisplay don`t work.

You have three ways:

1) You should start with /ProductDisplay page

2) Or add index.jsp page and start with this page.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:forward page="/ProductDisplay" />
</body>
</html>
```

3) And bad variant - add scriptlet to page Patient.jsp with code and start whith this page

```
PatientsDao p = new PatientsDao();
ArrayList<Patient> patients = p.getPatients();
request.setAttribute("patients", patients);
```

And remember never call servlets directly. Only through any servlet. 
This is bad practice

Comment: Add scriplet to which page, Patient.jsp ? I did that, now getting a compile error "PatientsDao cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: I edited my answer. Its not three steps. Its three different ways. And third is the worst ways. You have this error because you forget add import.

Comment: Doesn't work, sorry. Methods 1 and 2 produce horrible runtime errors and method 3 doesn't compile :(

Comment: I copy your code. Create DB with your name and table name. And its work. Show your all code on Github, plz

Comment: I update the .jsp file above adding a single line right after the <body> tag that you suggested: <jsp:forward page="/ProductDisplay" />  The code looks exactly as it appears above. When I run Tomcat and go to Patient.jsp page I get a nasty looking exception that keeps running in Eclipse console for 10-15 seconds and then stops. The error is: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Patient.jsp at line 13.    Line 13 is the statement that you suggested adding: <jsp:forward page="/ProductDisplay" />

Comment: Yes you added the tag in the wrong place. Now you starting `/Patient.jsp`, this page go forward to servlet `/ProductDisplay` in method `doGet`,  this method forward to `/Patient.jsp` and again, again...  I wrote that you need to add `index.jsp` page in folder web(copy-paste all from my answer) and start with this page. You automatically goes to this page when you start Tomcat.

Comment: And delete `<jsp:forward page="/ProductDisplay" />` from Patient.jsp

Comment: If you dont want add index.jsp file you may start automatically from /ProductDisplay at the start tomcat. Add this tags to web.xml <welcome-file-list> <welcome-file>ProductDisplay</welcome-file> </welcome-file-list> – vadtel 50 mins ago    Delete

Comment: Ok, after adding index.jsp page and removing that forward tag from Patient.jsp file everything works fine. Thank you so much!